# Python: List Comparison to find unique element count of lists

Tags: python, algorithm, list

i am trying to implement a string comparison algorithm in Python for one of my projects. As i am new to python, i'm learning on the go. But i'm stuck at a step of the algorithm. 
At the moment i have list of lists. It is sorted and groupby the length.

```
mylist = list(list(i[1]) for i in itertools.groupby(sorted(mylist, key=len), len))
>>> [
      [['pat'],['cut'],['rat']],
      [['sat','pat'],['cut','pat']], 
      [['rat','cut','pat'],['put','cut','bat'],['mat','gut','lit']]
      [[...]]...
    ]
```

If we consider mylist[2] elements in a column, it looks like this

```
mylist[2] 
>>> [['rat','cut','pat'],
     ['put','cut','bat'],
     ['mat','gut','lit']]
```

i want to compare each column and return the most frequently occurring element count. i.e at index zero, it is 3(all three are different). For index one it is 2 (since 'cut' appears  twice), and in index two, it is 3 again. likewise i need to repeat the process to all the lists of mylist.

It feels im stuck here. Can somebody suggest me a suitable method, perhaps a List Comprehension?

Thank You.

Comment: What do you mean by "the most frequently occurring element count"? I don't see how column 0 has a count of 3; are you counting the number of distinct elements, or the number of times the most frequent element appears?

Comment: For counting, use `collections.Counter`. That being said, I don’t understand what you are doing.

Comment: hmm.. i mean the number of different tokens of each column. since rat, put and mat are different count is 3. In the second column, it has only two different tokens. cut and gut. so the count is 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set` to extract the unique elements, and `zip(*list_of_list)` as a trick to "transpose" a list of list. Try this:

```
lst = [
  [['pat'],['cut'],['rat']],
  [['sat','pat'],['cut','pat']], 
  [['rat','cut','pat'],['put','cut','bat'],['mat','gut','lit']]
]

print map(lambda ll: [len(set(l)) for l in zip(*ll)], lst)
```

Output:

```
[[3], [2, 1], [3, 2, 3]]
```

Edit: To get the minimum value of each list, a trivial addition to the above will do:

```
print map(lambda ll: min([len(set(l)) for l in zip(*ll)]), lst)
```

Output:

```
[3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Yes. This is the output i wanted. In fact, i want to get the least value of each set. Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "least value of each set"?

Comment: minimum value of each list. For the above example, it would be 3,1,2

Comment: I've edited the answer for that. It's trivial and you might have figured how to do that already.